# How do I maximise the sum in this game?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So,  I was asked this question in an interview:

There are two friends playing a game in which they select a number from an array containing `n` positive numbers. Both friends select one number at a time, and both the players play the game optimally. And you have to find out what's the maximum sum (of numbers that are being selected) that you could obtain after the game ends. The constraints that were given after I gave the answer to the same question without constraints were:

1. On the first move of both players, they can select any number.
2. Apart from first move, they can only select the number which is adjacent to the previous number in the given array and which hasn't been selected by the first and second player up until that moment in the game. (Clarification as edit)

And if a player is not able to make a move, he/she stops playing. And the game ends when both players cannot make a move.

Now, the solution that I gave was:

1. Make a structure containing the value as well as the index of the value in the input array.
2. Make an array of the previous structure and store the values of first step in this array.
3. Sort this array in non-decreasing order on the basis of values.
4. Start selecting a value in a greedy manner and print the maximum value.

They were looking more for a pseudo-code though I can code it too. But, the interviewer said this will fail for some cases. I thought a lot on which cases this will fail but couldn't find any. Therefore, I need help in this question.

Also, if possible, please include a pseudo-code of what I can do to improve this.

Edit: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question, specifically in 2nd point. What the interviewer meant was:

If it is not the first move of the player, he has to choose a number which is adjacent to one of the number he already selected in previous moves.

Also, yes, both the players play the game optimally and they choose numbers turn by turn.

Edit2: So, the same question was asked from my friend but it was modified a little. Instead of an array, what he was given was a graph. So, like in my case, I can select only the indices that are adjacent to my previously selected indices, what he was given was an undirected graph (adjacency list as input) and he could select only those vertices in a particular move which are directly connected to any of the previously selected vertex.

For eg: 
Let's say the number of positive integers is 3. The value of those integers are `4`, `2`, `4` and also, if I name the positive integers by `A`, `B` and `C`, then,

```
A - B
B - C
```

The above was the example that my friend was given and the answer to the above would be `6`. Can you just point me in the right direction as to how I can begin with this? Thanks!

Comment: Of course your solution is wrong. Say, the array is: `20 20 20 20 20 1 1 1 1 50` (10 items). You sort it in non decreasing order gives you `50 20 20 20 20 20 1 1 1 1` . Now, you select 50 to start and the other player selects 20. Now, due to neighbor select constraint, you can only select 1's while he can always select a 20. At the end, you lose, 54-100.

Comment: Do you have to find the maximum sum of numbers being selected(by both players) or something else?

Comment: If all are positive integers, then definitely the maximum sum = sum of all elements in array and this occurs when both players start from left and right boundaries and proceed towards each other. I think there is more to this.

Comment: @Dante. if you start first at the boundary, I move next to you and block  you, then take everything for myself. You don't want to start at the boundaries if you move first (in fact you never want to start there).

Comment: @IVlad So our aim is to devise an algorithm that will increase our chance of winning and not merely maximizing sum of elements being selected by both players.

Comment: @Dante. I understood it as finding the maximum sum you can achieve if you move first and your opponent plays optimally. The question could be a little clearer though.

Comment: The question could be worded better.  Start with the rules, then make it clear you're supposed to implement a computer program that plays the game, not some kind of meta thing about the result of two other players playing the game.  (although with deterministic best play, that's kind of the same thing).  Do both players make their moves at the same time?  Or can player2 box out player1 by going right next to his first move?

Comment: @Dante there is no mindgames here. 1st player must pick the item that bisects array in a way two resulting arrays sums difference is less, than picked number. if it's achievable, p1 wins, if not, p2 wins.

Comment: @PeterCordes i think the best interpretation of `both friends select one number at a time` is that they are taking turns. other way they will both choose the best item first turn. and it's obvious, the best 1st move for p2 will be right next to p1's. there is not much choice

Comment: Hopefully,I best captured what the interviewer wanted?

Comment: See my edit once of the question.

Comment: @JohnDoe I deduced the same from second point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if you make the first move at index `x`, if your opponent plays optimally, their first move will have to be at index `x-1` or `x+1`. Otherwise, they will have elements that they could have picked but didn't. To see this, consider two non-adjacent starting points:

```
-------y-------------x-------
```

Eventually they will both take elements from the array and end up with something like:

```
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So you can relocate the starting points to the middle `yx`, obtaining the same solution.

So, assume you move first at `x`. Let:

```
s_left_x = a[0] + ... + a[x]
s_right_x = a[x] + ... a[n - 1]

s_left_y = a[0] + ... + a[x - 1]
s_right_y = a[x + 1] + ... + a[n - 1]
```

Let's say you want to win the game: have a larger sum than your opponent at the end. If your opponent picks `x + 1`, you want `s_left_x > s_right_y`, and if your opponent picks `x - 1`, you want `s_right_x > s_left_y`. This is ideally, in order to win. It's not always possible to win though, and your question doesn't ask how to win, but rather how to get the largest sum.

Since your opponent will play optimally, he will force you into the worst case. So for each `x` as your first move, the best you can do is `min(s_left_x, s_right_x)`. Pick the maximum of this expression for each index `x`, which you can find in `O(1)` for each index after some precomputations.

Comment: I guess you assume that the array is sorted. Which is not the case. Also, check my edit once of the question.

Comment: @JohnDoe no, I don't assume the array is sorted. If you point out where it looks that way, I'll try to clarify. But I see now that the number can be adjacent to any numbers picked so far... will edit later to clarify or delete.

Comment: Instead of pre-computation, I think you can find the element that balances the left and right sums in one pass.  Keep track of two positions, starting from the beginning and end of the array.  Work inwards, keeping the sums ~even.

Comment: @JohnDoe I have updated my answer. I don't think your edit changes the solution actually. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @IVlad, thanks a lot for your extended help. However, I just had one more doubt when the same question was asked from my friend in a little different format. Please see my Edit2 and let me know how I can proceed with that? Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm not sure about a graph. I think you'd need a different algorithm for that. In any case, the problem is quite different. If you're interested in a solution for that, you should post another question. You can link to this one as a related question from there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this is solution, that is formulated more briefly:

1st player must pick the item that bisects the array in a way two resulting arrays' sums difference is less, than picked item's value.

If it's achievable, p1 wins, if not, p2 wins.

Obviously, on his 1st move p2 must choose the item next to p1's, as it is the only way for him to get maximum sum. He chooses the item on the side, where the sum of remaining items is bigger. This will be the maximum sum p2 can get also.

p1's maximum sum will be the sum of remaining items (items that are on the side, that p2 has not chosen plus item p1 picked in first move).

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned that both player play the game optimally,I am going to present an algorithm under this assumption.

**Definitely if both players play optimally,then definitely the sum they obtain at the end would be maximum,otherwise they are not playing optimally.**

There are two different cases here:

**I make the first move and pick element at position x**

Now because we have to obey the condition that only adjacent elements could be picked,let me define two arrays here.

left[x]: It is the sum of elements that can be obtained by adding

```
array[0],array[1]....array[x-1],the elements left to x.
```

right[x]: It is the sum of elements that can be obtained by adding

```
array[x+1],array[x+2]....array[n-1],the elements right to x.
```

Now,because the other player also plays optimally,what he will do is he will check what I can possibly achieve and he finds that,I could achieve the following:

```
array[x] + left[x] = S1
```

**OR**

```
array[x] + right[x] = S2
```

So what the other player does is finds the minimum of the S1 and S2.

**If S1 < S2 this means that if the other player picks element at x+1,he just took away the better part of array from us because now we are left with a lesser sum S1**

**If S1 > S2 this means that if the other player picks element at x-1,he just took away the better part of array from us because now we are left with a lesser sum S2**

**Because I am also playing optimally I would in the very first move pick such x which has minimum absolute value of (right[x]-left[x]),so that even if our opponent takes the better part of array from us,he is only able to take away minimum**

Therefore,If both players play optimally, the maximum sums obtained are:

**Update.**

```
x + left[x]  and right[x]//when second player in his first move picks x+1
```

Therefore,in this case the moves made are:

```
Player 1:Picks element at position x,x-1,x-2....0.

Player 2:Picks element at position x+1,x+2,....n-1
```

Because each player has to pick adjacent element to the previously picked element by him.

**OR**

```
x + right[x] and left[x]//when second player in his first move picks x-1
```

Therefore,in this case the moves made are:

```
Player 1:Picks element at position x,x+1,x+2....n-1.

Player 2:Picks element at position x-1,x-2,....0.
```

Because each player has to pick adjacent element to the previously picked element by him.

**where x is such that we obtain  minimum absolute value of (right[x]-left[x]).**

Since OP insisted on posting pseudocode,here is one:

Computing the left and right array.

```
for(i = 0 to n-1)
{
 if(i==0)
  left[i]=0;
 else left[i] = left[i] + array[i-1];

 j = n-1-i;
 if(j==n-1)
  right[j]=0;
 else right[j]= right[j] + array[j+1];
}
```

The left and right arrays initially have 0 in all positions.

Computing max_sums.

```
Find_the_max_sums()
{
 min = absoulte_value_of(right[0]-left[0])
 x = 0;
 for(i = 1 to n-1)
 {
  if( absolute_value_of(right[i]-left[i]) < min)
  {
   min = absolute_value_of(right[i]-left[i]); 
   x=i;
  }
 }
}
```

Clearly Both space and time complexity of this algorithm is linear.

Comment: Your last function will just compute the value for the first move. How do I find it over the entire game? I want the maximum sum for the entire game.

Comment: @JohnDoe My last function determines the value of x for which maximum value occurs. You are right that it is related to first move,but the maximum sum is decided by the first move.

Comment: @JohnDoe The maximum sum has two possibilites which I have clearly mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @JohnDoe The last function will give us the the position of partition,such that array is partitioned into two parts of maximum sum (according to the Rules Of The Game).

Comment: @JohnDoe Feel free for any queries.

Comment: but then at each move, how will I determine the value that it will pick? Will it be something like, the above logic will be repeated each time a number has to be picked up? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe Ok,I see the confusion now.

Comment: thanks a lot for your extended help. However, I just had one more doubt when the same question was asked from my friend in a little different format. Please see my Edit2 and let me know how I can proceed with that? Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: but then, the indices as you mentioned won't simply increment by `1` since all of them would be different. And it will work I guess for telling to an interviewer, but could you just provide the teeny tiny hint as to how can I start with the greedy approach if their is the possibility of having more than 2 adjacent vertices? Thanks a lot once again. You have been extremely helpful. :)

Comment: how do I go on deciding the first vertex that needs to be picked? That's the final hint that I need. :)

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Ivlad's anwser, there exists a strategy for which p1 will never lose (there may be a draw in the worst case). She can always find a `x` such that the sum she obtains is not smaller than p2's sum.

The proof goes as follows -- sorry this more math that coding. I consider an array of positive numbers (up to a constant translation, there is no loss of generality here).

I denote  `a = [a[0],...,a[n]]` the array under consideration  and for any `k<=l`, `S[k,l] = a[k]+...+a[l]` the sum of all terms form rank `k` to rank `l`. By convention, `S[k,l]=0` if `k>l`.

As explained in previous comments, picking up `a[k+1]`  guarantees p1 to win if:

```
a[k+1] >= max( S[1,k]-S[k+2,n] , S[k+2,n]-S[1,k] )
```

Let consider `D[k] = S[1,k] - S[k+1,n]`, the difference between the sum of the first `k` terms and the sum of other terms. The sequence `D` is decreasing, negative for `k=0` and positive for `k=n`. We can an index `i` such that:

```
D[i] <= 0
D[i+1] => 0
```

(in fact,  one of the two above inequalities must be strict).

Substituting for `S` and noticing that `S[1,k+1]=S[1,k] + a[k+1]` and `S[k+1,n]=S[k+2,n] + a[k+1]`, the two inequalities in `D` imply:

```
S[1,i] <= S[i+2,n] + a[i+1]
S[1,i] + a[i+1] >= S[i+2,n]
```

or equivalently:

```
a[i+1] >= S[1,i] - S[i+2,n]
a[i+1] >= S[i+2,n] - S[1,i]
```

In other words, choosing `a[i+1]` is strategy with which p1 cannot lose.

In fact, this strategy offers the largest payoff for p1. Note that it is not unique even if all terms of the array are strictly positive. Consider for example `a=[1,2,3]`, where p1 can indifferently choose 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, the maximum sum in any game will always be the addition of a number of adjacent values, from a given split position S to either position 1 or position N. Player 1 chooses an initial split point S and Player 2 chooses his side of the array to sum (so Player 2 also chooses Player 1's side). One player will add from 1 to S (or S-1) and the other from S (or S+1) to N. The higher sum wins.

In order to win the game, Player 1 must find a split position S such that both addtions from 1 to S-1 and from S+1 to N are strictly smaller than the sum of the other side plus the value of S. This way no matter what side Player 2 chooses to add, its sum will be smaller.

Pseudocode:

```
1. For each position S from 1 to N, repeat:
1.1. Add values from 1 to S-1 (set to zero if S is 1), assign to S1.
1.2. Add values from S+1 to N (set to zero if S is N), assign to SN.
1.3. If S1 is smaller than S+SN and SN is smaller than S+S1, then S is the winning position for Player 1. If not, repeat.
2. If you have found no winning position, then whatever you choose Player 2 can win choosing in turn an optimal position.
```